# How to retrieve event id properly from button and use for delete Ajax Request

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am displaying a simple table populated data from an API. The table functions with post/put/delete/edit requests. The DELETE request is sometimes successful and sometimes it isn't. From the console output, I am pressing the delete button multiple times and then it works. I believe the component has not rendered completely and "event.target.id" value is not available to the DOM when the axios call is made.

-How do I tell the component and/or delete function to wait for the id value?

-Should I use state to store the id attribute or maybe the data-contactid attribute instead of event.target.id?

Thanks.

[image]

[image]

```html
class AllContacts extends Component {
    state = {
        contactData: [],
        id: '',
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        apiClient.get('contacts', {
            onSuccess: ({ data }) => { 
                this.setState({contactData: data}) 
            },
            onError: () => { /* would be cool to do something here */ }
          }) 
          .catch(err => console.log('error: ', err))     
    }

    
    handleSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log(event)
               
        apiClient.delete(`contacts/${event.target.id}`)
        .then(res => {
            console.log(res);
            console.log(res.data);
        })
      }

    renderTable = () => {
        return (
        <div>
            <Table>
                <TableHead>
                  <TableRow>
                    <TableCell>                    
                        <SimpleModal />                      
                    </TableCell>   
                  </TableRow>
                  <TableRow>
                    <TableCell>AVATAR</TableCell>
                    <TableCell>FIRST NAME</TableCell>
                    <TableCell>LAST NAME</TableCell>
                    <TableCell>EDIT</TableCell>
                    <TableCell>DELETE</TableCell>
                  </TableRow>
                </TableHead>
                <TableBody>
                    {this.state.contactData ? this.state.contactData.map((contact, i) => (
                    <TableRow key={i}>
                        <TableCell>
                            Avatar{/* <img src={this.state.contactData.avatarUrl} width="100" height="100" alt="Avatar"/> */}
                        </TableCell>
                        <TableCell>
                            {contact.firstName}
                        </TableCell>
                        <TableCell>
                            {contact.lastName}
                        </TableCell>
                        <TableCell>
                            <Button variant="raised" color="primary">
                                EDIT
                            </Button>
                        </TableCell>
                        <TableCell>
                            <Button data-contactid={contact.id} id={contact.id} onClick={this.handleSubmit} variant="raised" color="secondary">
                                DELETE
                            </Button>  
                        </TableCell>
                    </TableRow>
                    ))
                    :null}
                </TableBody>
            </Table> 
        </div>
        )
        
      }
    

    render() {
        console.log(this.state)
      return (
          <div>
            {this.renderTable()}
          </div>
      )
    }
  }
   


export default AllContacts
```

Comment: Could you open up the network tab and show if there are any details from the server what the error is? And could you show what id is sent to the server (you crossed that out in the image)?

Comment: Yes, the error from the server is: {"errors":["param is missing or the value is empty: data"]}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the following:

```
handleSubmit = id => event => {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log(event)

        apiClient.delete(`contacts/${id}`)
```

In your delete button:

```
onClick={this.handleSubmit(contact.id)}
```

But you can still delete something that's already being deleted when clicking the button multiple times.

You could optimistically remove that contact (assuming the request succeeds) before sending the request:

```
handleSubmit = id => event => {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.setState({contactData: data.filter(c=>c.id!==id)});
```

When there is an error you have to see if it was because the contact is already gone or because some other error.

Imagine this is a multi user application then user A can try to delete a contact it's seeing that user B has already deleted so depending on the API; trying to delete a contact that's already gone could cause an error that should not be an error (end result is the same since contact is already gone)

Comment: Do you know how I can get the component to rerender after I delete something?  It's showing the deleted table row even after the successful  delete request.

Comment: @Tom I updated the answer to optimistically update the table, when the results come in it depends on how the API works.

Comment: Do I put this in my then promise part?

Comment: @Tom No, you put it right before making the request. Optimistically updating your UI means you assume the delete request will work. You can put some code in the `.catch` that will set an error on state to be shown and re request the the users as you do in `componentDidMount`

Answer (score 1):

You can try it without going for event,

```
<Button data-contactid={contact.id} id={contact.id} onClick={()=>this.handleSubmit(contact.id)} variant="raised" color="secondary">
```

And change the handleSubmit function as,

```
handleSubmit = (id) => {
        console.log(id)

        apiClient.delete(`contacts/${id}`)
        .then(res => {
            console.log(res);
            console.log(res.data);
        })
      }
```

Comment: will cause event is not defined error in handleSubmit

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much. Do you know how I can get the component to rerender after I delete something? I know in react, the component won't render again unless the state changes. It's showing the deleted table row even after the successful request.

Comment: Yes, in react, dom rerenders in state and props change. So when you delete an item, changing the this.state.contactData array will automatically rerender the dom

Comment: `So when you delete an item, changing the this.state.contactData array will automatically rerender the dom ` I think you are confusing React with Angular observable since that's not the default behavior of React state and will go against immutable state, one of Reacts core concepts.

Comment: I meant, the object, contactData  in the state using setState(). U can't directly change a state variable. Anyone with a basic understanding knows that :)

Comment: @Tom, this.forceUpdate() will also rerender the component but react doesnt recommend that.